# Opening same file in two views in Brackets

Tags: brackets

Is there a way without downloading an extension to view the same file in two views in brackets?

I want to split my view vertically and have the same file open on either side.

Comment: I tried a few times just now and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file from the File Tree, not from the Left-Right opened-files lists.

1. Open the file in one of your panes.
2. Select the file of the other pane to activate such a pane.
3. Select the file in file tree (you might use "Show in File Tree" option if cannot locate it quickly).
4. Open the file from the File Tree (not from the Left-Right opened-files lists).

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. :(

Namely: I need to "copy->paste" a lot of code functions from one part /from footer/ to other part /to header/ of one huge file.

What I do:
I save my file as a copy (under another name) and open it in other pan, near with original.
After successful copy-pasting I delete a clone document.
Profit! :)

Brackets sprint 6 build 1.6.0-16680 (release 3df0ac6fa)
build timestamp: Tue Jan 12 2016

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but thought I would post an answer for reference since the feature has since been added to Brackets.

> What's New in Release 1.6 [Split View (Same Document) by swmitra](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/11820) :
>   Same document can now be opened in both the panes, when in split view.

As of 11/04/16, Brackets is now in Release 1.7 (stable) and this "feature" appears to be a permanent addition (although I'm personally looking for a way to disable it - I don't like it).